# In Redux-Observable / RxJS how do you emit a combination of actions and helper functions

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

After a user has been authenticated i need to call 2 functions (`AsyncStorage.setItem` and `setAPIAuthorization`) followed by 2 redux actions (`LOAD_USER` and `SET_SESSION_USER`). How would I achieve this based off the attempt below? Or should I create redux actions for both functions also?

```
const loginUserEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('LOGIN_USER'),
    mergeMap(() =>
      from(axios.post(`/auth`, {})).pipe(
        mergeMap(response =>
          of(
            AsyncStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data.token),
            setAPIAuthorization(response.data.token),
            {
              type: 'LOAD_USER'
            },
            {
              type: 'SET_SESSION_USER',
              user: response.data.user
            }
          )
        ),
        catchError(error => console.log(error))
      )
    )
  );
```

Thanks to Anas below, here is the update that I am using to achieve what i want. Successful so far. After I store the `id_token` it is included in the header of any subsequent api calls. For this reason I need to ensure that the `id_token` is saved before calling `LOAD_USER` which is an api call.

```
const loginUserEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('LOGIN_USER'),
    mergeMap(() =>
      from(axios.post(`/auth`, {})).pipe(
        mergeMap(response => {
          return new Observable(observer => {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data.token);
            setAPIAuthorization(response.data.token);
            observer.next(
              {
                type: 'LOAD_USER'
              },
              {
                type: 'SET_SESSION_USER',
                user: response.data.user
              }
            );
          });
        }),
        catchError(error => console.log(error))
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the session storage is a side effect.
So better to do it in a [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html),

Your epic should only return actions as output (actions In, actions Out). If you do it that way, redux will complain that you're not returning plain actions.

I will still create action creator for `{ type: 'LOAD_USER' }` and `{ type: 'SET_SESSION_USER'}` just because it's cleaner.

```
const loginUserEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('LOGIN_USER'),
    mergeMap(() =>
      from(axios.post('/auth', {})).pipe(
        tap((response) => {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data.token)
          setAPIAuthorization(response.data.token)
        }),
        mergeMap(response =>
          of(
            {
              type: 'LOAD_USER',
            },
            {
              type: 'SET_SESSION_USER',
              user: response.data.user,
            }
          )
        ),
        catchError(error => console.log(error))
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask, does the `tap` complete before the `mergeMap` is called? The `id_token` which I save to storage is needed in the `LOAD_USER` action so I need to ensure that it as always saved before calling `LOAD_USER`.

Comment: @theseboys There is no guarantee that `tap` will finish before `mergeMap` starts. In order to do have such a behavior, you need to wrap your `AsyncStorage.setItem` in an observable. But regardless, I don't think it's a good idea to access the `storage` in the reducer because you're gonna be introducing side effects to your reducer which suppose to be pure. A better approach would be to pass the response to your action `{ type: 'LOAD_USER' }` and use it in the reducer without introducing side effects.

Comment: Thanks. How does the updated epic look that I've added to the opening post?

Answer (score 0):

another simple way is to use `switchMap`

```
switchMap(() => [
  {
    type: 'LOAD_USER',
                },
  {
    type: 'SET_SESSION_USER',
    user: response.data.user,
  }
])
```

It automatically wrap result into observables as long as it's an array. So you no longer need to `of()` it. I use it quite a lot in my project.